# Windows bcdedit stores config parameters in NVRAM? what does it mean?

Tags: bios, uefi, bcdedit, bootmgr

In Win10 `bcdedit /?`, the help text says it will store boot configuration parameters in nonvolatile RAM (NVRAM) entries.

[image: bcdedit /?]

Is that ridiculous? As far as I know, bcdedit stores configs in disk files.

To be concrete...

※ If a typical x64 PC's BIOS determines that it should boot the PC in Legacy BIOS mode,

1. It load the first disk sector(the MBR sector) into RAM and execute.
2. This MBR code in turn loads the first sector of the active partition(OS boot sector) into RAM and executes.
3. The OS boot sector in turn loads the `\bootmgr` file (no filename extension) into RAM and executes.
4. The `bootmgr` code finds `\Boot\BCD` (no filename extension again) to get [boot configurations we previously set by running `bcdedit`].

※ If a typical x64 PC's BIOS determines that it should boot the PC in UEFI mode,

1. It finds an EFI System Partition and loads `\EFI\Boot\bootx64.efi` into RAM and executes.
2. bootx64.efi then reads `\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\BCD` for boot configuration parameters.

There seems nothing to do with NVRAM. Could it mean something (in bcdedit context) that does not exist on a harddisk, but on some PC mainboard chip(let me call it BIOS-area)?

If `bcdedit` could really store/change some data in BIOS-area, please cite an example. I mean, what kind of `bcdedit` parameters could cause BIOS-area data to be changed?

Comment: “Is that ridiculous?” - No; It’s not; NVRAM most definitely takes a part in UEFI boot entries.

Comment: You missed the word "previously"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You skipped quite a few steps for UEFI mode. You're right that "It finds an EFI System Partition and loads \EFI\Boot\bootx64.efi" is one of them, but it is the *fallback* behavior (officially, it's the "removable disk" behavior) – there is a step or two that involve the motherboard's NVRAM before reaching this point.

First, as described in the [UEFI Specification](https://uefi.org/specs/UEFI/2.10/) ([PDF](https://uefi.org/sites/default/files/resources/UEFI_Spec_2_10_Aug29.pdf)), the firmware provides extensive "boot" and "runtime" services (similar in principle to BIOS interrupts), among them the "Variable Services" ([section 8.2](https://uefi.org/specs/UEFI/2.10/08_Services_Runtime_Services.html#variable-services)) which allow the OS to save various key-value pairs in system NVRAM. (Typically it's the same flash memory aka "CMOS" that the firmware uses for its own settings, and many systems actually store *all* firmware settings as EFI variables.)

Usually the OS will expose the Variable Services API to user-space programs in some way, e.g. Windows provides [SetFirmwareEnvironmentVariable()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setfirmwareenvironmentvariableexw) while Linux has a virtual filesystem at `/sys/firmware/efi/efivars`.

Also, as described in [section 2.1](https://uefi.org/specs/UEFI/2.10/02_Overview.html#boot-manager) and [section 3](https://uefi.org/specs/UEFI/2.10/03_Boot_Manager.html), the firmware has its own *boot manager* which "will attempt to load UEFI drivers and UEFI applications (including UEFI OS boot loaders) in an order defined by the global NVRAM variables". The firmware boot manager is basically the same F8 or F10 "boot menu" that you've probably used, but in addition to listing whole disks, now it also lists individual .efi files for operating systems.

(This feature actually **predates UEFI** by quite a bit – the "previously" in your quote refers to either [Alpha AXP](https://web.archive.org/web/20201231033033if_/https://jdebp.eu/FGA/arc-boot-process.html) and/or Itanium IA64 EFI, both of which ran Windows; both of which existed at the same time as Boot.ini (i.e. before BCD); and both of which had firmware boot managers. I don't have links to specifications for either, though.)

The EFI "boot manager" mainly uses NVRAM variables named `Boot####` (4-digit number), `BootOrder` and `BootNext` to list the installed operating systems. Whenever Windows installs its own BOOTMGR (which can be done manually using `bcdboot.exe`), it also uses the EFI Variable Services (through the API provided by Windows) to create a Boot0000 entry pointing at `\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\Bootmgfw.efi`, titled "Windows Boot Manager".

You can in fact see these entries via `bcdedit /enum firmware`, though they'll be heavily translated into Windows BCD-like format (as the same tool handles *both* EFI and BCD entries), or by running `efibootmgr [-v]` from within Linux or FreeBSD:

```
BootCurrent: 0003
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0003,0005,2003,0002,2001,2002
Boot0000* UEFI Onboard LAN IPv4     PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1c,0x0)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/MAC(3417eb7eda76,0)/IPv4(0.0.0.00.0.0.0,0,0)RC
Boot0001* UEFI Onboard LAN IPv6     PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1c,0x0)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/MAC(3417eb7eda76,0)/IPv6([::]:<->[::]:,0,0)RC
Boot0002* HDD1-1 (Samsung SSD 860)  PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1f,0x2)/Sata(0,0,0)/HD(1,GPT,b7245b9a-d13f-4d97-8bff-901255bfd7ad,0x1000,0x100000)RC
Boot0003* Linux Boot Manager        HD(1,GPT,b7245b9a-d13f-4d97-8bff-901255bfd7ad,0x1000,0x80000)/File(\EFI\systemd\systemd-bootx64.efi)
Boot0004* Arch Linux LTS            HD(1,GPT,b7245b9a-d13f-4d97-8bff-901255bfd7ad,0x1000,0x100000)/File(\EFI\Linux\vmlinuz-linux-lts.efi)
Boot0005* EFI Shell                 HD(1,GPT,b7245b9a-d13f-4d97-8bff-901255bfd7ad,0x1000,0x80000)/File(\shellx64.efi)
```

So the real steps for UEFI firmware (again described in [section 3](https://uefi.org/specs/UEFI/2.10/03_Boot_Manager.html)) are:

1. It reads EFI filesystem paths from the `Boot####` variables as indicated by BootNext or BootOrder, then attempts to load and run each file as an .efi executable, in the specified order. (Boot items not listed in BootOrder are inactive.)
2. If none of the active Boot#### variables could be executed, it *usually* falls back to the ["removable disk"](https://uefi.org/specs/UEFI/2.10/03_Boot_Manager.html#removable-media-boot-behavior) behavior of scanning all disks for an EFI System Partition that contains `\EFI\Boot\Boot[cpuarch].efi` and executing that. This is also what happens if you manually select a whole disk from the firmware's boot menu.

   (Practically all systems that I've seen apply this to fixed internal disks as well. This allows booting the installed OS whenever the disk is moved to another motherboard or the NVRAM data is lost for whatever reason, as well as installing an OS for EFI even if the install media can't be booted in EFI mode for some reason and therefore Variable Services are unavailable.)
3. (As a last resort, some firmwares (mostly those built on EDK2) will run an embedded copy of the EFI Shell, which is an interactive CLI somewhat similar to MS-DOS and lets you run an .efi file manually. Some other firmwares instead will open a file browser GUI where you can choose which .efi file to run. Others just drop to the firmware setup screen.)

This EFI boot process was heavily inspired by [the one found in Alpha](https://web.archive.org/web/20201231033033if_/https://jdebp.eu/FGA/arc-boot-process.html) (which was the primary WinNT platform before x86). To some extent, NTLDR and Boot.ini in Windows NT/2000/XP imitates the Alpha AXP [firmware-based boot entries](https://www.betaarchive.com/wiki/index.php?title=Microsoft_KB_Archive/172806), including even the use of ARC paths for the system disk.

Similarly, Windows XP was also available for EFI on the Itanium IA64 where it relied completely on the EFI boot manager (as far as I know, it did not have its own boot menu), so "These parameters were previously in..." most likely refers to XP's use of native EFI boot manager features alongside the x86 version that used Boot.ini.

(So I suspect that the current Windows Boot Manager and its BCD was created because Microsoft kept finding the AXP- and EFI-provided interfaces inadequate, but it still mimics EFI-style boot to some extent, e.g. even BIOS installations now have a dedicated "system partition" and no longer place BOOTMGR directly on C:\.)

Perhaps because of the latter, the `bcdedit` tool manages both kinds of boot entries – both EFI firmware as well as Windows BCD – through a unified interface. For example, by default `bcdedit` will list the Windows BCD entries used by BOOTMGR, but if you specify the `/enum firmware` option, then it will list EFI NVRAM entries used by the firmware boot menu (although in a format very different from the real thing).

Comment: Thank you for your abundant answer. But, I think I need time to verify this. On PC-A, `bcdedit /enum firmware` really lists some "new" entires with description text "Windows Boot Manager", however, that does NOT manifest those enum-ed info is from NVRAM. I think those "firmware" entries are still recorded in `BCD` file, because, when I copy PC-A's `B:\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\BCD` to another PC (call it PC-B) as D:\test\BCD.bin , `bcdedit /store D:\test\BCD.bin /enum firmware` list exact the same entries. So, the conclusion is still pending.

Comment: It is possible that they are copied from firmware to BCD at some point, but they always reflect external changes to NVRAM entries (e.g. made by another OS), and changes to those entries are also reflected in the firmware.

Comment: You’re missing an additional optional step. A number of firmware implementations will check for `\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi` (the standard Windows boot loader path) either before or after looking in the removable media paths even if it’s not defined in the boot entries. Some (very much _not_ compliant) implementations even blindly ignore the `Boot*` variables and even the removable media paths, and _only_ boot that specific path and nothing else.

Comment: @user1686 A harsh question: If BCD config entries could be stored into motherboard NVRAM, then when one day I remove my harddisk from the motherboard, will UEFI firmware preserve those entries or delete them? It's a dilemma for UEFI firmware code, because, the firmware code does NOT know whether the harddisk is remove by me temporarily or permanently.

Comment: @JimmChen: 1) they're not BCD entries – they're read by the firmware boot manager, whereas BCD is for the Windows Boot Manager; 2) it varies – depends on which manufacturer's EFI firmware you're using; some implementations automatically delete entries for missing disks (even during a temporary removal) while others keep them forever (until manually deleted). For example, Aptio (ASUS) and HP firmwares seem to keep such entries, whereas if I remember correctly, Gigabyte likes to automatically delete them...

Comment: Why are you saying they are not BCD entries? My first comment verifies that, `BCD` file content carries those `/enum firmware` entries.

Comment: Yes, I mean, I highly suspect that, the `/enum firmware` and `SetFirmwareEnvironmentVariableEx` API does not  store/load data into the *firmware* but actually into disk file. They have word *firmware* in their names just because they may **indirectly** affect the UEFI firmware behavior. It's just a naming metaphor, or, call it a cheat. Naming cheat is not bad if no better vivid names can be conceived.

Comment: I'm saying they are not real BCD entries because they exist regardless of Windows being installed on the system (and therefore regardless of the system _having_ a BCD file in the first place). For example, the same entries can be seen and created through the EFI Shell, through Linux, or through FreeBSD. At most, they're _cached_ within the BCD and `bcdedit /enum firmware` shows the cached copy.

Comment: [20221118.A] Conversely, I think BCD file content is the final, non-volatile storing area, while the UEFI firmware RAM(yes, I mean RAM, not NVRAM) is the cache for those BCD entries. I think this can work, in theory.

Comment: @user1686 [20221118.B] You say, "some implementations automatically delete entries for missing disks", THEN I'd like to ask, if those removed disks re-plug into the motherboard the second day, will the UEFI system recognize the OS on them and boot them immediately? If YES, then what's the benefit of storing OS boot config into the NVRAM? If NO, isn't the UEFI system too stupid? I expect the answer to be YES, bcz that's what our normal PC users have expected.

Comment: a) No, that's not the case. I think you're assuming that every OS disk has a BCD, which it doesn't, and it is easy to verify this experimentally using an empty HDD with no BCD file (nor Windows Boot Manager) on it. b) I wasn't the one who created it, but *usually* the advantage is the ability to have several OS installed on the same disk without requiring one particular OS to know about all others (the way that e.g. GRUB is used on BIOS systems).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140733/discussion-between-jimm-chen-and-user1686).

Comment: I admit now, the values I set via `bcdedit` goes into `BCD` file as well as firmware NVRAM. I experiment it in a VMware workstation 16 VM. (1) Install Win10 and Ubuntu 22.04 onto the the same VM. (2)Let Win10 execute `bcdedit /set {a1a963eb-...} description "Ubuntu-2204me"`. (3)Let VM reboot into UEFI firmware UI, I see `Ubuntu-2204me` in EFI boot menu(default is `ubuntu`). (4)Boot into WinPE and rename `B:\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\BCD` to `BCD.set-aside`. (5) Reboot into EFI again, `Ubuntu-2204me` is STILL THERE. So I know the firmware really keeps a copy of the boot entry name `Ubuntu-2204me`.